# make border non transparent if div is transparent

Tags: html, css

Is there some CSS way to make div transparent, but borders not transparent?

HTML:

```
<div class="ts-twentytwelve-description">into quality solutions</div>
```

CSS:

```
border-left: 9px solid #fff;
border-right: 9px solid #fff;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.86;
filter: alpha(opacity=86);
```

Comment: have you try this ? border-left:9px solid #FFF;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.86); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that :

```
.ts-twentytwelve-description {
border-left: 9px solid #fff;
border-right: 9px solid #fff;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.86);
}
```

With background-color:rgba(value) you can add opacity only for background-color.
For IE you have [generator here](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); // or transparent
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use this solution:

```
<div class="border_div">
   <div class="content_div">
       your content here
   </div>
</div>

.border_div {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.content_div {
    opacity: .86;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4XVZ/2/

CSS:

```
.ts-twentytwelve-description {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 9px solid #000;
border-right: 9px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
background-color: transparent;
opacity: 0.86;
filter: alpha(opacity=86);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ts-twentytwelve-description">into quality solutions</div>
```